# How to calculate difference between two dates in {dd-mm-yyyy} format in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, datetime, react-native-navigation, moment-timezone

I want to calculate the difference between two dates in react native my date format is in {dd-mm-yyyy}
I have converted the timestamp using moment and put in a variable that is in format
{dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm: ss}
so I did is split the date and time so now I have a date in another variable in this format{dd-mm-yyyy}
I have tried several methods it is showing me, NaN.
here is the code:

```js
const responseJson = [[{"start_date": 1618905463, "end_date" : 1618955463 }]]

var st_date = responseJson[0][0]['start_date']; {
  var time_st = moment.unix(st_date).format("DD-MM-YYYY h:mm:ss");
  setStartDate(time_st)
}
//alert(startdate);
var start = time_st.split(' ')[0];
//alert(start);

var end_date = responseJson[0][0]['end_date']; {
  var time_en = moment.unix(end_date).format("DD-MM-YYYY h:mm:ss");
  setEndDate(time_en)
}
//alert(enddate);
var end = time_en.split(' ')[0];
//alert(end);
date1=startdate;
date2=enddate;
var z = moment('date1', 'DD-MM-YYYY'); 
var w = moment('date2', 'DD-MM-YYYY');
var v = w.diff(z, 'days');
//alert(v);
//alert(diff);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: var z = moment(date1, 'DD-MM-YYYY');
 var w = moment(date2, 'DD-MM-YYYY');

instead of 'date1' put date1

Comment: Please fix the [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) of your question, and make this an actual [mcve] (remove all the unnecessary comments)

Comment: Also there is nothing react specific about calculating diffs in dates - I made you a snippet. Please change my `responseJson` and add `setStartDate`  to make the snippet a [mcve]

Comment: @Andreas Comments are useful to see the mindset of OP

Comment: @mplungjan Comments that explain something yes. Commented code maybe. But a bunch of `alert()`s and `console.log()`s of values doesn't really help. Nothing in OPs script would log anything right now. So which statement is it that logs `NaN`?

Comment: @Fahimzuhair i tried doing that i still showed me NaN in alert

Comment: @Andreas yes I will definitely keep this in my mind

Comment: @Shru_v in the above code setStartDate, setEndDate is missing need to check value of startdate, enddate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to go back and forth between `moment` instances and strings. Once you have used `moment.unix` to turn a unix time intoa  moment instance you can just use it directly to get the number of days (or hours, minutes, seconds as needed) between the two.

```js
const responseJson = [[{"start_date": 1618905463, "end_date" : 1618955463 }]]

var st_date = responseJson[0][0]['start_date']; 
var time_st = moment.unix(st_date)

var end_date = responseJson[0][0]['end_date']; 
var time_en = moment.unix(end_date)

console.log(time_st,time_en);
var v = time_st.diff(time_en, 'days');
console.log(v)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```